# Django - How to check if an user is visiting the website everyday

Tags: python, django

As per title, in Django, when and where i should store information about the user access? I'm already logging the user login/logout using Django built-in signals, but what if the user is already logged on that machine? How can i detect this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to do the same thing on my Django project. The problem is that the `last_login` variable doesn't helps since it is updated at the user login, and If the user cache his session the variable will never be updated.

One solution is to create a decorator, and use it on your view's. In that way if the user uses your site, the variable will get updated.

This is an example of how to do it:

```
from functools import wraps
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

def W_update_user_login(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        request = args[0] 

        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            user=User.objects.get(username=request.user)
            user.last_login=timezone.now()
            user.save()

        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

If you add the previous code in to your `views.py` file, you will be able to decorate your functions. ex:

```
@W_update_user_login
def your_view_function(request):

    #
    # your normal code..
    #
    return HttpResponse....
```

Comment: This seems like a really good idea! Thanks for the hint, i will try it soon!